# Subkey yq query on docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker-compose, yaml, yq

What I'm looking for is a [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/) query that returns the service names that are using
a specified volume for a given `docker-compose.yml` file.

For example, in the stripped down `docker-compose.yml` file below, say I am looking for the names of all services that
use the volume `v-app-olorin`.

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  arwen:
    this: that
    volumes:
      - v-app-mithrandir:/data/mithrandir
      - v-app-olorin:/data/olorin
  boromir:
    volumes:
      - v-app-mithrandir:/data/mithrandir
      - v-app-stormcrow:/data/stormcrow
  cirdan:
    volumes:
      - v-app-mithrandir:/data/mithrandir
      - v-app-olorin:/data/olorin
volumes:
  v-app-mithrandir:
    name: v-app-mithrandir
  v-app-olorin:
    name: v-app-olorin
  v-app-stormcrow:
    name: v-app-stormcrow
```

The expected response would be:

```
arwen
cirdan
```

I can match simple key values with something like this:

```bash
yq e '.services | with_entries(select(.value.this == "that")) | to_entries | .[] | .key' docker-compose.yml
```

```
arwen
```

But I'm having trouble matching an element of the volumes array. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's an expression that does that:

```
yq '.services[] | select(.volumes[] | contains("v-app-olorin")) | key' docker-compose.yml
```

Explanation:

- splat out the services entries into their invidiual nodes `.services[]`
- select the ones that have "v-app-olorin" in their volumes array: `select(.volumes[] | contains("v-app-olorin"))`
- get the key of that services entry

Disclaimer: I wrote yq

Comment: Looks great, but I got this error:
`Error: Parsing expression: Lexer error: could not match text starting at 1:35 failing at 1:38.
 unmatched text: "con"
`

Wrong version maybe?
`yq (https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/) version 4.10.0`

Comment: Upgraded with brew to 4.27.3 and this works perfectly... of course.  Thanks!